# Facebook Login Iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to login Facebook through an Iframe in an app developed in IntelXDK.
The problem is that the page go outside of the Iframe.
In the app  i've

```
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%; position:fixed; margin-left:-10px;" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://...."></iframe>
```

while in my page i've this:

```
 var paramsLocation=window.location.toString().indexOf('?');
  var params="";
  if (paramsLocation>=0)
    params=window.location.toString().slice(paramsLocation);

top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MYID&redirect_uri=http://MYURL';
```

How can I obtain to stay in the Iframe after facebook login?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cordova `InAppBrowser` to do facebook login in HTML5 packaged app, you can use this jquery plugin to login to facebook oauth:

https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

```
$.oauth2({
    auth_url: 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    response_type: 'token',
    client_id: 'CLIENT-ID-FROM-FACEBOOK',
    redirect_uri: 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/oauth2callback',
    other_params: {scope: 'basic_info', display: 'popup'}
}, function(token, response){
    makeAPICalls(token);
}, function(error, response){
    alert(error);
});
```

This is will work in [IntelXDK](http://xdk.intel.com)